# xsl-fo add spacing between table and image

Tags: xsl-fo, spacing

I have a table placed on a land-scape page. I want to position an image to the left of the table, and add some spacing between the image and the table.

Here's my code:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master   
master-name="A4"
page-width="29.7cm"
page-height="21.0cm"
margin-top="0.5cm"
margin-bottom="1.0cm"
margin-left="4.0cm"
margin-right="1.0cm"
> 
<fo:region-body margin="1.0cm" writing-mode="rl"/>
<fo:region-before extent="5.0cm" />
<fo:region-after extent="1.0cm"/>
<fo:region-start margin="3.0cm" />
</fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">

<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">

<fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" > 

<fo:block text-align="center">

<fo:external-graphic src="path to image" content-height="scale-to-fit" height="1cm" width="7cm"  scaling="non-uniform" />
</fo:block>



</fo:block-container>

</fo:static-content>

<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="50%" height="100%" left="5cm">

<fo:table-column column-width="13cm" />

<fo:table-column column-width="8cm" />

<fo:table-body>

<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>

        Lorem ipsum text 

        </fo:block>

    </fo:table-cell>

</fo:table-row>


</fo:table-body>

</fo:table>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

As you can see, I've tried to insert the image in to region-start area of the page, however I can't seem to add spacing between the image and the table. How would I go about doing this or could I have done things differently to acheive the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Because your block-container is rotated:

```
<fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" >
```

the image is rendered with a vertical size of 7 cm: the "height" and "width" of the blocks inside the container are rotated as well. So your header is 7 cm high.

You also haven't specified any space at the bottom of the header. You could wrap the header in a block-container that has a bottom margin:

```
<fo:block-container margin-bottom="1 cm">
```